# Fastest Way To Open HTML File in Browser using VScode - Current Extensions Failing

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to be able to quickly open my html files from VScode to Chrome.

I have been using the extension [Open in Browser](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=techer.open-in-browser), but not it appears to be failing.

I've tried [this extension alternative](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=peakchen90.open-html-in-browser), but it doesn't work on my rig either.

As a workaround I am currently searching for the file in finder and dragging it to chrome.

Any suggestions to streamline this process or alternative extensions to open html files in browser?

Rig Details: 2014 Macbook Air Running Mojave 10.14.1

Answer (score 0):

Works for a bunch of extensions:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-open-in-application

[image]

Example of config for Windows:

```json
"openInApplication.applications": {
    "html": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
}
```

Comment: Out of the box this extension isn't working for me.  Did it require any configuration up front for you before you started using it?

Comment: I think it needs path to apps. Edited the answer.